# Cloud deploy error in wolfram engine Docker

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy, free-wolfram-engine

With the following docker image with wolfram engine setup: https://hub.docker.com/r/wolframresearch/wolframengine

Using CloudDeploy gives the following error msg :

CloudObject::srverr: Cloud server is not able to complete a request

I'm using the Wolfram Engine free for developers license

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `::srverr` message tag is an internal server error (HTTP status 500), so it's a problem on the server side, not your Docker side, and you should report it; it's a bug. Chances are it was transient, but by reporting it Wolfram can check things like the server logs. But some things you can do when this happens to narrow it down or even maybe work around it:

- log out and log in again; this should bounce you to a different server where it may work
- see if it can be reproduced
- try it in a different client environment, especially switching between in-cloud and coming in remotely from cloud; in this case, you were coming from outside the cloud, so log in to the wolframcloud.com webapp and try the same thing in a notebook there
- vary the request slight: try a CloudExport instead of CloudDeploy, switch between a named and unnamed CloudObject destination, if using a name, try a different directory, if deploying something large, deploy something small, whatever you can think of